# Grid Column Filter list from data in that column

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, grid, angular-ui-grid

I am trying to see if there is a way to automatically populate the list of options in the column filter for the **AngularJS ui-grid** with the unique values from the column it's filtering on.

I can see how this column filter works when making the filter a drop down select=

```
 type: uiGridConstants.filter.SELECT, selectOptions: [{ value: '1', label: 'male' }, { value: '2', label: 'female' }]
```

But I don't want to have to define the option values.  I want the grid to automatically place in that list each unique value from the column its filtering on.

Does the grid already do this?

If not, does a custom filter have access to the grid column values so I could return a list of unique values to the selectOptions array?

Comment: I'm trying to find a solution to this as well.  [I came across this really ugly solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30200924/3500241), but there really should be a better way to do it.  IMO, what you're suggesting should be how ui-grid works by default when `type: uiGridConstants.filter.SELECT`.

Comment: Please post some workaround for this. How is it possible that there ain't any solution yet.