# UI-Grid gridOptions -> selectOptions as Variable not possible?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, angular-promise

I just tried to use this code:

```
field: 'field1',
filter: {
    term: 1,
    condition: uiGridConstants.filter.STARTS_WITH,
    placeholder: 'starts with...',
    ariaLabel: 'Starts with filter for field1',
    flags: { caseSensitive: false },
    type: uiGridConstants.filter.SELECT,
    //selectOptions: [{ value: '1', label: 'male' }, { value: '2', label: 'female' }],
    selectOptions: [$scope.DropdownEntries],
    disableCancelFilterButton: false
}
```

The gridOptions  selectOption array which come back form DropdownEntries is empty because the variables in DropdownEntries() are not accessible if gridOptions are not set, they come from a Webservice and it takes longer to load them as gridOptions are set.

Is there any possibility to "reload" the gridOptions after I`m sure that all variables are accessible ? Or is there another way to solve this problem

- I am new in AngularJS and Ui-Grid thanks for helping me !

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the selectOptions with an empty array and reassign them when the data becomes available

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30199831/dynamically-change-gridoptions-columndefs) question.

Answer (score 0):

Then you should wait for that promise to be resolved and after that set selectOptions, something like this:

```
$http.get(url).then(function(response) {
    gridOptions.filter.selectOptions = response.data.dropdownEntries;
})
```

Another possibility is to resolve that promise before entering the controller that sets ui-grid options.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#example